# Responsive Photo gallery JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, photo-gallery

I am looking for a responsive photo gallery. I would like all the photos in b&w and when your mouse is over a photo that she gets colored. Does anyone have an idea ? a demo available ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this example would help:

> http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/

Comment: Do you know how to custom this plugin. I would like to make appear the photo description under it in a kind of box shadow